# Need to write a cast operator

Tags: c, gcc

The function expects a pointer to a two-dimensional array `[4][5]`. In fact, we can instead submit a pointer to a one-dimensional array `[20]`. Ie source code will look like:

```
extern f (int a[4][5]);
int b[20];
void func (void)
{
  f (b);
}
```

Ie it is perfectly working code (provided that the interior of the array `b`, we will be laid out so as they would in a two-dimensional array). However, the compilation will be issued a warning (due to inadequate types):

```
$ gcc t.c -c
t.c: In function 'func':
t.c:7: warning: passing argument 1 of 'f' from incompatible pointer type
```

Need to write a cast operator to warning was gone

Comment: The type of `b` is `int *` while the argument is of type `int (*)[5]`. That is kind of bad. Change either the prototype or pass the correct parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extern f (int a[4][5]);
```

A parameter defined with an array type is *adjusted* at compile time so it's really of pointer type, specifically a pointer to the array's element type. In this case, `int a[4][5]` is an array of 4 elements, each of which is an array of 5 `int` elements. After the adjustment, the actual type is pointer to array of 5 `int`, so the above is exactly equivalent to:

```
extern f(int (*a)[5]);
```

Note that the `4` is silently ignored. (To put it mildly, this is not my favorite C language feature.)

Now you declare an array of 20 `int`s:

```
int b[20];
```

and try to pass it to `f`:

```
void func (void)
{
  f (b);
}
```

Since `b` is an expression of array type, it is (in most but not all contexts) implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's first element. (The exceptions are when the array expression is the operand of `sizeof`, unary `&`, or when it's a string literal used to initialize an array, none of which apply here).  So this call:

```
f(b);
```

is equivalent to:

```
f(&b[0]);
```

The argument is of type `int*`, which is not compatible with the expected type `int(*)[5]`.

If the parameter type for `f` is fixed, then you need to pass it a pointer to an array.  For example, you might change the definition of `b` so it's compatible with what `f` expects.

Here's how I might write it:

```
extern f (int (*a)[5]);

int b[4][5];

void func (void)
{
    f(b);
}
```

I've changed the declaration of `f` so it more clearly indicates the actual type of the parameter, and I've redefined `b` as a 2-dimensional array. `b` still contains 20 `int` elements, but it's of a different type.

Keep in mind that there are two distinct array/pointer language rules at play here. One is that a parameter of array type is *adjusted* (at compile time) so that it's really of pointer type. The other is that an expression of array type, in most but not all contexts, is implicitly *converted* to a pointer to the array's first element.

These two rules work together to confuse new C programmers about the relationship between arrays and pointers.

See also section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Your function is expecting an argument of type pointer to a 1D array, i.e, `int (*)[5]`. The prototype is similar to

```
extern f (int (*a)[5]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your argument of function is treated as

```
int (*)[5];//as in function argument arrays are treated as pointer
```

But when you pass b as it is of type int[20] which is implicitly treated as

```
int *
```

So how you can assign int(*)[5] with int * without the anger of compiler! Or even you can face error on other compilers

Comment: The phrase "implicit conversion" is misleading. The type of the parameter is *adjusted* at compile time to a pointer type. This is a distinct rule from the one that says that array expressions are implicitly converted to ("decay" to) pointers.

Comment: Rule is also that array and pointers can be used interchangeble in function argument so and array and pointer in function argument are treated as sameand only base address get passed

Comment: As I said, there are two distinct rules. One is that a parameter defined with an array type is adjusted to be of pointer type. The other is that an array expression is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element unless it's the operand of `sizeof` or `&`, or is a string literal used to initialize an array object. The latter rule is not specific to function arguments. The language *could* have had either rule without the other. Recommended reading: section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: These two are different rules i know but are dependent because at compile time function argument of type int [] is treated as int *

Comment: The two rules work together, but I wouldn't call them "dependent". `a` (which is a parameter, not an argument) looks like it's of array type, but it's adjusted to pointer type (the first rule). In the call `f(b)`, the argument `b` is *converted* to `int*` (the second rule). But you could as easily call `f` with an argument that's already of type `int*`; in that case, no conversion would occur.

Comment: Now is there any misconcept in my question?if yes please tell me as iam nojt a experienced programer.if there is no such things you can vote my answer up i ll not mind.....plz

Comment: Rather than critique your answer, I've written [one of my own](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21944040/827263).